# PrimeFaces multiple file upload example bigger buttons

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

As simply as that... I don't know why all the buttons of the file upload in prime faces are very big. I tried with the code on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
font-size: 90% !important;
}
```

this line inclued in PrimeFaces  Document. Check it your self.

Comment: `            <p:fileUpload
                fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.handleFileUpload}"
                mode="advanced"
                multiple="true"
                sizeLimit="2000000000"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|csv)$/"
                styleClass=".fileupload-buttonbar{
                    font-size: 50%;
                }"
                />` already have this, but it doesn't change the component... In the document says **As skinning style classes are global, see the main Skinning section for more information** but I cannot find the **Skinning section** !!